# How to write efficient sql query that return latest student score(by date) in each lesson?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

the table structure is as follows:

```
student lesson  score   Date
Allen   Math    12      9/11/12
Allen   Math    19      9/11/14
Allen   Physics 10      9/11/12
Joe     Physics 15      9/11/12
Joe     Physics 13      9/11/15
```

the result should be:

```
student lesson  score   Date
Allen   Math    19      9/11/14
Allen   Physics 10      9/11/12
Joe     Physics 13      9/11/15
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the most generally efficient query is a correlated subquery with the right index:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from t t2
                where t2.student = t.student and t2.lesson = t.lesson
               );
```

The index you want is on `(student, lesson, date)`.

Note that in some databases, other methods may be a bit faster.  But as a general rule I find that this has good performance.